# WPF XAML - Bind Context Menu Item to Main Window DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a Window with the DataContext binded to a ViewModel.
In my ViewModel I have a Command named for example

```
HideShowSingleWindow
```

My Window has a context menu for the tray icont that is dynamically filled. Now I need to bind the Command on MenuItem click to the HideShowSingleWindow command in the Window datacontext.

I tried

```
<Grid>                        
     <tb:TaskbarIcon
      IconSource="/Icons/main.ico"
      ToolTipText="SCADA Control Center" 
            DoubleClickCommand="{Binding Path=HideShow}">
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <MenuItem Header="Windows" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RegisteredWindows}">
                                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsLoaded, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=HideShowSingleWindow}" />
                                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Show/Hide All" Command="{Binding Path=HideShow}" />
                            <Separator />
                            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding Path=Quit}" />
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                </ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
     </tb:TaskbarIcon>
</Grid>
```

Where we can see:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=HideShowSingleWindow}" />
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

ContextMenu doesn't inherit DataContext of `tb:TaskbarIcon` because **context menu doesn't lie in same Visual tree as that of its placement target** (*taskbar icon in your case*).

So, get the DataContext explicitly and bind with command like this:

```
<Setter Property="Command"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                         AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, 
                       Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.HideShowSingleWindow}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit. Thank you for your reply. This fixed my error in OutputWindow, but it still doesn't work. I tried binding the Quit command (that I'm sure it works) but..nothing..

Comment: `HideShow` and `HideShowSingleWindow` resides in same class?

Comment: If they are in same class and `HideShow` is working then I see no reason for other command to not work. Try debugging your bindings using converter.

Comment: It's the same thing I'm trying to understand! I tried using a converter placing a breakpoint in Convert method but It's never called O.o

Comment: Make sure command `HideShowSingleWindow` getter is public. If it is then try changing path. Start with `PlacementTarget` see if it's passed correctly to the converter, then check if `DataContext` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the setter as follows:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tb:TaskbarIcon}}, Path=DataContext.HideShowSingleWindow}" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
I get this error message:
"System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.TaskbarIcon', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.HideShowSingleWindow; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')"

Comment: Blame on me: I should know 'cos I bumped against thousands of times! Rohit gave you the right answer...